# SpriteKit Autoresumes and auto pauses iOS8

Tags: objective-c, ios8, sprite-kit

The scene auto pauses on applicationWillResignActive and auto unpauses when applicationDidBecomeActive is run. I am looking to either have the scene pause on applicationWillResignActive via the nsnotification and not auto resume when applicationDidBecomeActive is run. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

AppDelegate

```
 - (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
// Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"backgroundPause" object:nil];
}
```

GameViewController

```
- (void)handleNotification:(NSNotification *)notification {

if ([notification.name isEqualToString:@"backgroundPause"]) {
    SKView *skView = (SKView *)self.view;
    skView.scene.paused = YES; //pauses scene

    [self.lblPaused removeFromSuperview];//removes any lingering pause menu items
    [self.lblPausedHelp removeFromSuperview];

    self.lblPaused = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    self.lblPaused.center = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2 - 125, self.view.frame.size.height/2 - 40);
    self.lblPaused.text = @"PAUSED";
    [self.lblPaused setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:66]];
    [self.lblPaused sizeToFit];
    self.lblPaused.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [self.view addSubview:self.lblPaused];//adds pause label

    self.lblPausedHelp = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    self.lblPausedHelp.center = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2 - 145, self.view.frame.size.height/2 + 40);
    self.lblPausedHelp.text = @"tap anywhere to resume";
    [self.lblPausedHelp setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:26]];
    [self.lblPausedHelp sizeToFit];
    self.lblPausedHelp.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [self.view addSubview:self.lblPausedHelp];//adds pause label
}
```

}

Comment: "pause the view, pause the world"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it's a bug in spritekit.  No matter what you do, the game will unpause itself in `applicationDidBecomeActive`

I asked the same question here.  [pausing spritekit game on app launch / exit .. iOS8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26317553/pausing-spritekit-game-on-app-launch-exit-ios8) You have to subclass SKScene and override the `paused` property to get it to work.  It's weird you have to do that.  It really shouldnt have so many problems, but thats the only way I could get my game to stay paused

EDIT:  okay, I translated the code to objective-c.  I hope this is useful to you because my objective-c was rustier than i expected.

**AppDelegate.m**

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:@"pauseGameScene" object:nil];
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:@"stayPausedNotification" object:nil];
}
```

**SKView Subclass**

```
@interface MySKView : SKView
- (void) setStayPaused;
@end

@implementation MySKView

bool _stayPaused = false;

- (void) setPaused:(BOOL)paused{
    if (!_stayPaused) {
        super.paused = paused;
    }
    _stayPaused = NO;

}


- (void) setStayPaused{
    _stayPaused = YES;
}

@end
```

**GameViewController**

```
@interface GameViewController : UIViewController

-(void)pauseGame;

@end

@implementation GameViewController

SKScene *_scene;
MySKView *_skView;

-(void)pauseGame{
    _skView.paused = YES;
    _skView.scene.view.paused = YES;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(pauseGame) name:@"pauseGameScene" object:nil];


    // Configure the view.

    _skView = [[MySKView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.frame];

    _skView.showsFPS = YES;
    _skView.showsNodeCount = YES;
    /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
    _skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = YES;

    // Create and configure the scene.
    _scene = [[GameScene alloc]initWithSize:_skView.frame.size];
    _scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;

    // Present the scene.
    [self.view addSubview:_skView];
    [_skView presentScene:_scene];

}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:_skView selector:@selector(setStayPaused) name:@"stayPausedNotification" object:nil];
}


@end
```

Comment: ive edited my answer.  i've tested this out and it worked for me.