# pause game when WillResignActive

Tags: ios8, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skaction

I have some spritenodes with SKAction();
They are child's of sknode with name world

If I press the pause button in the game its animation of the spirenodes

```
func pause(){
    if(isGamePaused)
        isGamePaused = false;
        world.paused = false;
    } else {
        isGamePaused = true;
        world.paused = true;
    }
}
```

But I cannot pause the game when is going in the background

```
 NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("goBG:"), name: UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification, object: nil);

func goBG(sender: AnyObject){
    self.isGamePaused = true;
    self.world.paused = true;

    println("bg"); // called
    println(world.paused);// return true
}
```

Comment: SpriteKit automatically pauses when your app moves to the background and resumes when the the app is active.

Answer (score 0):

You can add either try to observe the `UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification` instead of your `UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification` notification, or you can call a function in your AppDelegate method `applicationDidEnterBackground` where you pause the game.

Comment: can you give me an example?

Comment: UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification - dont pause the SKAction

Answer (score 0):

if anyone is still interested.  There's a solution for this issue here:

[SpriteKit Autoresumes and auto pauses iOS8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27576448/spritekit-autoresumes-and-auto-pauses-ios8/27583417#27583417)