# Using swift and spritekit, how do you stop the scene from unpausing after becoming active / moving to foreground?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have the following code in my AppDelegate:

```
func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "PauseGame"), object: self)
}
```

In my GameScene.swift file, I have the the observer:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(GameScene_split.pauseGame), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "PauseGame"), object: nil)
```

Here is the function that it calls:

```
@objc func pauseGame() {
    self.isPaused = true
    isGamePaused = true
    pauseButton.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "PlayButtonWhite")
}
```

Okay, so when the home button is pressed and the app goes into the background, this pauseGame function is indeed called because when I click back into the app, the pauseButton texture is has changed to the "PlayButtonWhite", but the game is not paused.

Any ideas on how to stop the game from automatically unpausing when the app becomes active?

Comment: This may be what you're looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26317553/pausing-spritekit-game-on-app-launch-exit-ios8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the game is resumed the scene is (somehow) automatically unpaused.

However you can check your property `isGamePaused` and pause the game again.

Here's the code for your Scene

```
override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {

    guard !isGamePaused else {
        self.view?.isPaused = true
        return
    }
}
```

Let me know if it works.